# Deserializing an RSS feed in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, rss

Is it practical / possible to use serialization to read data from an RSS feed? I basically want to pull information from my Netflix queue (provided from an RSS feed), and I'm trying to decide if serialization is feasible / possible, or if I should just use something like XMLReader. Also, what would be the best way to download the feed from a URL? I've never pulled files from anything but drives, so I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you can use LINQ, LINQ to XML is an easy way to get at the basics of an RSS feed document.

This is from [something I wrote](http://encosia.com/2008/02/05/boost-aspnet-performance-with-deferred-content-loading/) to select out a collection of anonymous types from my blog's RSS feed, for example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  XDocument feedXML = XDocument.Load("http://feeds.encosia.com/Encosia");

  var feeds = from feed in feedXML.Descendants("item")
              select new
              {
                Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
                Link = feed.Element("link").Value,
                Description = feed.Element("description").Value
              };

  PostList.DataSource = feeds;
  PostList.DataBind();
}
```

You should be able to use something very similar against your Netflix feed.

Answer (score 15):

The .NET 3.5 framework added syndication support. The **System.ServiceModel.Syndication** namespace provides a bunch of types to manage feeds, feed content and categories, feed formatting (RSS 2.0, Atom 1.0), etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx

You have a few options for serialization, but the simplest is probably best described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb536530.aspx

Comment: I took a look into this, but it appears the namespace only provides serialization options, not deserialization options, unless I overlooked something.

Comment: You "deserialize" via the SyndicationFeed.Load static method. It automatically detects the input format. If you need more control, you can use the formatters directly...all of them have a ReadFrom method that takes an XmlReader.

Comment: I'll take a look into this when I get home, this is great to know if I ever need to do another RSS project.

Comment: But the SyndicationFeed.Load only accepts strictly confirming feeds. It will fail (unrecoverable) on a lot of Feeds.

Comment: How are you going to hand parse a non-conforming feed? The error space is limitless :-) But I agree it is almost useless because it chokes on the almost universally bad Date strings in pubDate.

Comment: You could always derive from the existing feed types and override the ReadFrom method to add custom error handling. If you really wanted to, you could write your own replacement feed types that were more forgiving, but still use the Syndication type to handle them in a format-independent way.

Answer (score 4):

```
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;

public static SyndicationFeed GetFeed(string uri)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
        {
            var ff = new Rss20FeedFormatter(); // for Atom you can use Atom10FeedFormatter()
            var xr = XmlReader.Create(uri);
            ff.ReadFrom(xr);
            return ff.Feed;             
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using .NET 3.0 or 3.5...then I would suggest using an XMLReader to read the document into an XDocument. You can then use LINQ to XML to query against and render the RSS feed into something usable.

Building something to de-serialize the XML is also feasible and will perform just as well (if not better) but will be more time intensive to create.

Either way will work...do what you're more comfortable with (or, if you're trying to learn XML serialization, go for it and learn something new).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792544/how-to-download-an-image-from-web-showing-the-progress-of-the-download-in-c-usin) for a pretty thorough download routine.

RSS is basically a derivative of XML.  I like [this link](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) for defining the RSS format. [This one](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/xml/rss/intro/) has a really basic sample.

Answer (score 2):

- Get rss schema from
  http://www.thearchitect.co.uk/schemas/rss-2_0.xsd
- Generate C# class using xsd.exe. ***xsd rssschema.xsd /c***
- During runtime, deserialize the rss
  xml using the xsd and class generated above.