# How to trigger an executable upon update of an RSS feed

Tags: c#, .net, rss

I have an RSS feed URL, that I can view in any Feed Reader.
This RSS feed is not controlled by me, it is only consumed by me.

This RSS Feed ([Office of Inspector General's Excluded Provider List](http://oig.hhs.gov/rss/LEIE.xml)) links to a page with download-able files.

These files are updated approximately once a month, and the RSS feed displays new "**unread**" items.

What I want to do is write something (in C#) that checks this RSS Feed once a week, and when a new item (i.e. a new download-able file) is available, triggers off an executable.

This is essentially like a very scaled-down RSS Reader, with the sole purpose of triggering an executable when a new item appears.

Any guidance, advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

- I need help in determining when a new
  item becomes available for
  download.
- The running of an
  executable I can do.
- The
  executable that will run, will process
  the downloaded file.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Do you need help determining if there are new items, or do you need to know how to start an executable once you've determined that there are new items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a commenter already noted, this question is quite broad, but here's an attempt to answer:

- You can either write a Windows Service (use a template that comes with VS/MonoDevelop) or you can write a simple console app that would be called by Windows Scheduler or Cron.
- The main code will use one of the many RSS feed parsers available:

There are plenty of examples here on SO. IMO, the simplest LINQ-based is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350153/deserializing-an-rss-feed-in-net)

I personally like [this approach](http://www.shrinkrays.net/code-snippets/csharp/simplified-csharp-atom-and-rss-feed-parser.aspx), also using LINQ.

- Once you parse the feed, you need to look for the value of the `Link` element, found by doing this from the SO example above:

....

```
var feeds = from feed in feedXML.Descendants("item")
              select new
              {
                Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
                **Link** = feed.Element("link").Value,
                Description = feed.Element("description").Value
              };
```

....

- So, now that you have the executable, you'll need to download it to your machine. I suggest you look into [this example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx):
- Now, that you have the file downloaded, simple use `Process.Start("Path to EXE");` to execute it.

Watch out for viruses in the exes!!!

Comment: I think he's going to run a particular executable that's already on his system, passing it information from the new item. I'm fairly certain he's not running downloaded executable files.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .Net 3.5 or above you can you the various classes within the [System.ServiceModel.Syndication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) namespace, specifically the [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class which exposes a LastUpdatedTime property that you can use to compare dates to know when to call your executable using the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method in the System.Diagnostics namespace.

```
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
            {
                SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

                if ((feed != null) && (feed.LastUpdateTime > feedLastUpdated))
                {
                    // Launch Process                            
                }
            }
```

Comment: I did try this as well, but it turned out that the feed that I am trying to read from did not provide any LastUpdateTime. Is it possible that they didn't provide that field with their feed? I was getting a null-type of date value (something like "01/01/0001" from that field.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to read the RSS feed from the URL, and then parse the data to determine whether a new item is available.

To read the feed, you'll want to use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). The simplest way:

```
var MyClient = new WebClient();
string rssData = MyClient.DownloadString("http://whatever");
```

You can then create an XML document from the returned string.

```
var feedXML = new XMlDocument();
feedXML.Load(rssData);
```

@dawebber shows how to parse the XML with LINQ. You'll want to check the date on each item to see if it's newer than the last date checked. Or perhaps you have a database of items that you've already seen and you want to check to see if the items you received are in the database.

Whenever you find a new item, you can fire off your executable using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a System Tray application. I've done several that screen scrape/monitor sites on a scheduled basis.  Here is a VERY simple start. I think you could do what you're looking for in a few hours.

http://alperguc.blogspot.com/2008/11/c-system-tray-minimize-to-tray-with.html